# How to support leagcy urls(Web forms type) in asp.net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have recently shifted to asp.net mvc, but we still need to support some legacy urls. What is the best way to handle this situation. Is it Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute() event in global.asax, that I need to use or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL [Rewrite module for IIS7](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite). Scott Hanselman has a good post on using URL rewrite to to handle legacy URLs [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx).

Another option, I believe you can simply add a route that matches your old url syntax.

Comment: Thanks Nate, but the problem is we have too many old urls to support
and our web configs are auto generated. Basically our application is a templated website platform and we support nearly 70 websites on it.
Is there any other way to get this working?